# How to retrive the Session data in Codeignitor

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller in which username checks with email id, and  I have registration area for this login. My need is to take session data including the session id from this code can anyone please help to sort out this?

**Controller**

```
public function login(){
    
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[5]');
    
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
        
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        
        //check user in db
        
        //session details for email and phone
        
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        
        $query1 = $this->db->get();
        $sess = $query1->row();
        
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where(array('email'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        
        $user = $query->row();
        
        
        //if user exists 
        if($user->email){
            //temp messAGE
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success",'you are logged in');
             
            //SET session variables
            $_SESSION['user_logged']= TRUE;
            $_SESSION['username']= $user->username;
            
            //redirection to profile page
            
            redirect("user/profile", "refresh");
        }
        else{
             $this->session->set_flashdata("error",'No Such Accounts found or please check username and password');
             redirect("home/index", "refresh");
         }
     }
     
    $this->load->view('login');
}
```

Comment: have you tried `$user->id` ?

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: I need to get the user id(primary key in registration table)  of the current logged in user dats my need

Comment: can you provide your table structure?

Comment: @Alshoja, You have to put your query part in Model and after $user = $query->row(); you have to add $user->userID . userID is the primary key of the registration table

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should put the query or CI ACTIVE RECORD in model, NOT IN Controller..

try this

```
$user->YourIDTableColumn
```

[CI DB ACTIVE RECORD](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: can i give this in controller??

Comment: yea it could even in the view too, just pass the data from your model function using $data['initial_array'] = $this->model_name->model_function();

and on your view just like this
$initial_array->YourIdTableColumn

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer after years since my experience in codeignitor was less at that time, I got confused I know it was a very simple question but it was the day I started in codeignitor so am writing the answer myself

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want id of session than you can use **session_id**. One more thing please use to load session in **application/config/autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Than you can use it in controller or model or view.

```
$this->load->library('session');

echo $this->session->session_id;
```

Or if you want some user info like email, id etc so you can use.

```
echo $this->session->userdata("email");
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get the user id to session data array, when user logs in.
Let's think your session data array is `user_data()`.

```
$userid = $this->session->user_data('user_id');
```